# ENUM data type in Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, enums

I would like to change a column in the DB for the status of a package in my application, something like:

- Pending ( should be default )
- Cleared
- Updated

The current column is boolean data type. I was thinking of changing to ENUM data type, but I'm not sure if that will be a good choice and how to go about it. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my knowledge this is what I would do..,
For eg: 
 In your DB

```
def change
create_table :statuses do |t|
  t.integer "status",:default => 1
end
```

end

and In model define your enum status

```
class Status<ActiveRecord::Base
  enum status {pending: 1, cleared: 2, updated: 3}
end
```